# SQL SERVER much faster than COUNT(*) with JOINS DB consists more than 30 million rows with 30 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_Table
```

making the system slow when we search for more than 30 million rows with 30 columns

so we interacted with the    sys.partitions, sys.tables

Query:

```
SELECT SUM(p.rows) FROM sys.partitions AS p
  INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
  ON p.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
  WHERE t.name = N'myTable'
  AND s.name = N'dbo'
  AND p.index_id IN (0,1);
```

However we want it for a JOIN. Please suggest

Execution plan for the Search Query:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyzzW-Oyf

Execution plan for the Count:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkkKfxO1M

Comment: If you want an accurate count, then use `count(*)`.  You can't use the system tables to estimate the result of a query; they just contain information about tables.

Comment: You have a wide table (table with many columns). If you have not got any non clustered indexes, and have just a one clustered index, when the query is performed the whole table is read (load). Create a non-clustered index which contained only the PK column(s). Then perform the count using the PK column in it. The new index will be used and less data will be read(load).

Comment: Can you include the execution plan?  How long does the query take to run?  Won't expect 30 mill to be a big deal on modern hardware.

Comment: It takes about 87sec @destination-data

Comment: If you can add the table schema and execution plan we might be able to help.

Comment: @supra, paste your actual execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/.

Comment: @destination-data 

Please check the execution plan

Comment: @DanGuzman Please check execution plan

Comment: @supra, not the plan image but the link to the actual plan uploaded to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/. Upload the plan with the joins you've tried rather than the one with no where or join clauses. Add create table DDL and indexes to your question.

Comment: [link] https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyzzW-Oyf

Comment: @DanGuzman We are planning for the JOIN. We dont have it yet. As you find my initial question is how could we go for a join for such a big DB